# Excel VBA looping through empty cells and retrieving row values

Tags: excel, vba

Me, again!

What I'm trying to do is to search in my range for any empty cells, and for each empty cell it finds, return some values from its row (offset).

The code I've pulled off so far:

```
 Private Sub buscarbtn_Click()
Dim fecha As Date: fecha = fechabsc.Value
Dim DESCUBIERTO As Boolean: DESCUBIERTO = False
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim diasem
Dim cell As Range


Hoja9.Range("L8").Value = fecha
fec = Hoja9.Range("L9").Value

If fec = "1" Then
    diasem = "D"
End If
If fec = "2" Then
    diasem = "L"
End If
If fec = "3" Then
    diasem = "M"
End If
If fec = "4" Then
    diasem = "W"
End If
If fec = "5" Then
    diasem = "J"
End If
If fec = "6" Then
    diasem = "V"
End If
If fec = "7" Then
    diasem = "S"
End If

Hoja9.Range("L10").Value = diasem
Set fecdes = prontuario1.Range("S:S").Find(what:=diasem, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

For Each cell In prontuario1.Range("S:S")

    If fecdes.Offset(0, 5).Value = "" Then
      DESCUBIERTO = True
      Debug.Print fecdes.Offset(0, 2).Value & " " & fecdes.Offset(0, 3).Value & " - " & fecdes.Offset(0, 4).Value
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

That Debug.Print I'm using was only a temporary solution for testing, since trying to print the whole row was only returning one result... and now I get multiple results of the same row.

I can only guess I'm overlooking something or using the For each loop totally wrong.

I know my code is reaaaally messy, but I'd be forever grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though your loop is referring to fecdes each time instead of cell, so for each cell in column S, it's re-evaluating fecdes.offset(0,5) and then printing values next to the fecdes cell. But presumably you at least want to have it evaluate the cell you're looping through in column S, right?

```
Private Sub buscarbtn_Click()
Dim fecha As Date: fecha = fechabsc.Value
Dim DESCUBIERTO As Boolean: DESCUBIERTO = False
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim diasem as string
Dim cell As Range


Hoja9.Range("L8").Value = fecha
fec = Hoja9.Range("L9").Value


select case fec
case 1
    diasem = "D"
case 2
    diasem = "L"
case 3
    diasem = "M"
case 4
    diasem = "W"
case 5
    diasem = "J"
case 6
    diasem = "V"
case 7
    diasem = "S"
end select

Hoja9.Range("L10").Value = diasem
r = prontuario1.cells(1,19).end(xldown).row

For i=2 to r
If prontuario1.cells(i,19).Offset(0, 5).Value = "" Then
  DESCUBIERTO = True
  Debug.Print prontuario1.cells(i,19).Offset(0, 2).Value & " " & prontuario1.cells(i,19).Offset(0, 3).Value & " - " & prontuario1.cells(i,19).Offset(0, 4).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, exactly... While fecdes has to match the diasem, what I need is to evaluate if given cell is empty, so I was trying to loop through S to check X (offset(0,5)): http://prntscr.com/krsz5w

do i need to declare something else for cell? i'm sorry if i'm a bit slow on this... and thank you for trimming my code!

Comment: Ok, so you're using column S as an anchor, and you want to output information about the rows where column X is blank, but only for certain values in column S? Do you want to do this for each possible value(D,L,M,W,J,V,S)? If so, it seems that you could use a bottom row counter like dim lstrw as long prontuario1.cells(1,19).end(xldown).row

Comment: After digging a bit more, I actually went with the row counter idea and it seems to work perfectly. Thank you so much.